# SUM of a specific field

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I wonder if you can help me in this situation.
What i want is:
If a specific field has a specific value (example, if on the column "item" one of the fields is equal to "item1") I want the sum of the cost of that "item1" (in this case, the cost is a fixed value, so I want the number of times that specific item appears x that value)
otherwise I want it to return 0

can you please help me?
thanks

I've tried something like this but no good:

if ({WGCDocLinhas.artigo}='TAXA')  >= 1
then
select SUM {WGCDocLinhas.precounit}
from WGCDocLinhas
where WGCDocLinhas.artigo}='TAXA'

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this in Crystal Reports.  My preference for what you describe would be to first group the report on the `Item` column.  This will reorder your dataset so that you can deal with each value of `Item` as a group and will also create a section in your report for Group Header and Group Footer.

Place the `Item` field in the Group Header, then place the field for `Cost` in the details section.  Now right click on the `Cost` field and select Insert Summary to create a Summary Field based on the `Cost` values.  You are going to need 2 summary fields, one for the COUNT of the number of time the `Item` appears in the details section for each value of `Item`, and another for the SUM of the `Cost` values.

If there are no detail records to count for a value of `Item`, the summary field will either show a value of zero, or they may just be NULL value and not show anything at all.  This will depend upon how you have setup your Crystal Reports environment.